# Error when reading in shp file using R

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm trying to read in a shapefile in R, but keep getting this error:

> nul character not allowed (line 1).

I have tried various shapefiles, all which work fine in QGIS and I have even tried open-source ones, all giving the same error.

I have tried various packages, they all give the same error, but here is an example with `readOGR`:

```
myShape <- readOGR("C:\", "ne_110m_coastline")
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: It appears that you're trying to read a binary file as ASCII. Have you tried using the `.shp` suffix on the file?

Comment: Try updating R and R studio.

Comment: Thanks!  I moved to readShapePoly and changed C:\ to C:// with the .shp and then it works fine.

Comment: If you have trouble with the import data, its always worth to check for spelling mistakes in paths/files. One way is to the directory of your file `setwd("C:/")` and then list your file `list.files(pattern="*ne_110m_coastline")` or all availabe .shp files using `list.files(pattern="*.shp$")`.

Answer (score 2):

When I work with shapefile data type. was made as follows:

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp
SHP <- shapefile("MODIS/SHP/PERU/All_Peru_R/DepaR_Peru.shp")
proj4string(SHP)
#[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
class(SHP)
#[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "sp"
plot(SHP)
```

the output is:

[image]

on the following link are some examples:

http://lincolnmullen.com/projects/dh-r/shapefiles.html

Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In R, file & folder paths have to use forward slashes ('/') as opposed to the default in Windows, back slashes ('\').   Alternatively, double-backslashes will work ('\\')

I just tried opening a shapefile in my C: drive and the code you used should work if you fix that aforementioned issue:

```
    myShape <- readOGR("C:/", "ne_110m_coastline")
```

I'll note that I tried it with C:\ and didn't get that exact error, so if my suggestion doesn't work, post back and maybe give a link to the file or something so we can see if there's something going on with the file itself.